# C# Controlling balanced parenthesis to recursive

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, parentheses

I am trying to write a function to control if the parenthesis included in a `string`are balanced or not.

I have written the following function:

```
public bool IsBalanced(string input)
{
    //last condition, gets out
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return true;

    int numOpen = 0;
    bool opened = false;
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (char.ToUpperInvariant(c) =='(')
        {
            opened = true;
            numOpen+=1;
        }
        if (char.ToUpperInvariant(c) == ')')
        {
            if (opened)
            {
                numOpen-=1;
                opened = numOpen > 0;
            }
            else
                return false; //incorrect position parentheses, closes but not opened
        }
    }

    return numOpen == 0;
}
```

I wanted to change it to a recursive function, but have not been able to do so. Could anyone give a hint how to do it?

Comment: Your function looks like it would accept ())((). Is that what you want?

Comment: Why do you want it to be recursive?

Comment: I'm not aware of any "lower" parenthesis characters, so I'm not sure why you're using `ToUpperInvariant()`. None of U+208D, U+FE59, U+FF08 nor U+207D get converted to U+0028 by that function (I'd have been surprised if U+FF08 or U+207D did, but decided to check anyway)

Comment: If you accept ())((), then you should not call this a balanced sequence of parentheses. If you are changing the definition to include extra sequences that don't make sense, then you should change the name. I suspect that you don't understand what a balanced sequence means. You should look it up, after which your question will probably change to become a duplicate of one of the previous questions on balanced parentheses such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711032/basic-recursion-check-balanced-parenthesis.

Comment: @DouglasZare you are right this question's code has to be rewritten, I will change it, about the question you reference i must say it is not a duplicate, because it is not C# exclusively.

Comment: @DouglasZare the code is not accepting "())(()", that is why there is a `opened` variable that controls if there is an opened parenthesis waiting to be closed. Therefore the code is checking balanced parenthesis.

Comment: @moreON just for improving performance on the algorithm

Comment: @DanielV: Ah, now I see what you did. Normally, people just keep track of the number of open parentheses, or a stack of open parentheses if they have multiple types of parentheses. They don't have your redundant variable `opened` that keeps track of whether the number of open parentheses is greater than 0.

Comment: @DanielV recursion isn't a magical performance wand. If you want something to perform faster, then you want it to perform faster. You don't necessarily want it to be recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to take a variant (numOpen in this case) as an argument.
Here is my code:

```
public bool IsBalancedRec(string input, int numOpen = 0)
{
    if (numOpen < 0)
        return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return numOpen == 0;

    char c = input[0];
    string rest = input.Substring(1);

    if (c == '(')
        return IsBalancedRec(rest, numOpen + 1);
    else if (c == ')')
        return IsBalancedRec(rest, numOpen - 1);
    else
        return IsBalancedRec(rest, numOpen);
}
```

And call this like `IsBalancedRec("so(m(eth)ing)")`.

Comment: I am not completely sure about your `IsBalancedRec`. What you mean by recursive calls?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I replaced the comment with my complete code.

Comment: Your function works, but it is interesting that it takes more time than my solution and Sinatr. (0,0420042 seconds). But works!!! thanks!

Comment: Maybe Substring is slow? You might get better performance by not using it.

Comment: @DanielV, do you want recursive solution **only** because you expect it to work faster? Or it is a requirement of job-giver? Recursive algorithms have overhead of method call itself and may eat plenty of stack memory.

Comment: @Sinatr This subject is very interesting thanks for bringing it up, I was with the false impression that I would provide a 'better' solution for this problem with a recursive implementation, but I know now that I was wrong in this case the iterative solution is a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your algorithm is not pretty. Here is a better one

```
int check = 0;
foreach (var c in input)
{
    if (c == '(') {
        check++;
    } else if (c == ')') {
        check--;
    }
    if (check < 0) {
        return false; // error, closing bracket without opening brackets first
    }
}
return check == 0; // > 0 error, missing some closing brackets
```

To make it (algorithm of checking for balanced brackets) recursive you can go with following

```
bool IsBalanced(string input)
{
    var first = input.IndexOf('('); // first opening bracket position
    var last = input.LastIndexOf(')'); // last closing bracket position
    if (first == -1 && last == -1)
        return true; // no more brackets - balanced
    if (first == -1 && last != -1 || first != -1 && last == -1)
        return false; // error - one of brackets is missing
    if (first > last)
        return false; // error - closing bracket is BEFORE opening
    return IsBalanced(input.Substring(first, last - first)); // not sure, might need to tweak it, parameter should be without first and last bracket (what is inside)
}
```

This simply remove first opening brackets and last closing bracket and pass what is left as parameter (recursively) until one of the end conditions is met.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but this does not answer the question (which is to transform the function to recursive).

Comment: I have tested you approach (not recursive) and it is faster (0,042 seconds) than mine (0,043 seconds) and definately more clean.

Comment: Sorry but your method doesn't work with this one:  **"ABC('')1 + ((3 :-) - DEF :-( =)) "**

Comment: @DanielV, isn't it a bit too late to suddenly include smiles (and `"..."` string literals?) into requirement list? Sounds like a completely different question to me.

Comment: actually the smiles have nothing to do, the actual issue is that your algorithm can not deal with something like "()(()())" as you can test by  yourself.

Comment: @DanielV, agree. That was a quick *out of head* recursive solution (didn't want to delete my answer). Non-recursive solution will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84549/discussion-between-danielv-and-sinatr).

Answer (score 2):

Implement with stack:

```
Stack myStak = new Stack();
    public bool IsBalanced(string input)
    {
        if (input.ToArray().Count() != 0)
        { 
            if(input.ToArray()[0] == '(')
            {
                myStak.Push('(');
            }
            else if(input.ToArray()[0] == ')')
            {
                if (myStak.Count != 0)
                    myStak.Pop();
                else
                {
                    //not balanced
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return IsBalanced(input.Substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            if (myStak.Count == 0)
            {
                //balanced
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //not balanced
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static bool IsBalanced(string input)
    {
        int numOpen = 0;
        while(input != "")
        {
            char c = input[0];
            input = input.Substring(1);
            numOpen = c == '(' ? (numOpen + 1) : (c == ')' ? (numOpen - 1) : numOpen);
        }
        return numOpen == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

// count no of left and right bracket or parenthesis and check counts

```
var InputStr= str.ToCharArray();
            int left = 0;
            int right = 0;
            foreach (char item in InputStr)
            {
                if(item  == '(')
                {
                    left ++;
                } else if(item  == ')')
                {
                    right ++;
                }
            }
            if(right == l)
            {
                return "1";
            }
            return "0";

  }
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to convert it to recursive, therefore you are not targeting the issue at hand